How to filter values from different rows
I want to count how many Approved jobs each employee has done. I could not capture employee name for approved jobs because Employee column has NULL value on Approved row. It has employee name on Assigned row. This is my data. For example how I could count the number of Approved jobs Jack has done? One job could have multiple Approved job status and there are hundreds of jobs for each employee. Any help?

I have already tried out FILTER formula but dont know how to match values from different rows.


You may use Table to Markdown Generator to make tables as markdown and post them in questions. Anyways, looks like Assigned is just 1 row so you can use that and JobId to check if the Job has been approved or not. Then sum up assigned jobs filtering by names.

You were on the right track to use the Unique function but you also needed to combine it with the filter function.
To test I created a sample data set similar to what you were describing :

I used the following function :
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(E3:E12, (D3:D12="Will") * (F3:F12="Approved"))))

FILTER(B2:B8, (A2:A8="Will") * (C2:C8="Approved")) :
filters IDs in column B for rows where column A is "Will" (You should change this value here depending on what employee your searching for) and column C is "Approved".
UNIQUE(...) :
then takes this filtered list and removes any duplicates.
COUNTA(...) :
counts the number of unique IDs left.
I tested this using : Excel 365 or 2019

It does not work for me, sorry. it returns value of 1 only for Wills

Make sure that the name is correct since it is searching for a specific name, case sensitive and everything.
Also make sure that all the data is being searched.  Excel should visually show you which field is being selected.

In Google Sheets, you could try the following:
=query(query(unique(A:C),
"select Col2,max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3",1),
"select Col3,count(Col3) group by Col3 label Col3 'Employee',count(Col3) 'Approved count'",1)

N.B. I am assuming your source table is in A1:Cx of your sheet. unique removes any instances of multiple approvals, the inner query pivots by the status column to bring each approved job into the same row as the assigned employee, then the outer query counts how many times each employee name appears.

Thank you so much for your efforts. It work for the first time but if I add more rows and increase the range, it does not work. Even if I change anything in the current data i.e increase the Approved jobs for William then again it fails. NOTE : I WANT TO COUNT EVERY APPROVED STATUS, so I have removed UNIQUE

The input range is A:C (i.e. infinite ranges), so this should work on any number of rows. More generally, I think you should add to your question a table showing the results you are expecting from the example source table, as it's not entirely clear to me what results you are expecting.

I have added an image in my question to show a desired result

Thank you for adding the desired result table, however I am now very confused as it appears to be identical to the result my answer gave you (except for the name ordering not being alphabetical in yours)...


In cell f1 I have the following formula
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A16,NOT(A2:A16="NULL")))

This gets a list of the unique names while filtering out the null values
In cell g2 I have the following formula
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16, "Assigned", $A$2:$A$16, $F1)

And in cell h2 I have the following formula
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16, "Approved", $A$2:$A$16, $F1)


Great! Thank you, Its giving me the same result as you have shown but I want to count all the APPROVED status for an employee. In this example Jack has 3 Approved status. Would you please tell me the changes accoridngly.

So in h1 put the following formula:
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$12, "Approved", $A$2:$A$12, $F1)
the only thing you're changing for the new column is the criteria for the first countifs element
and then copy down

No, It does not work because we have a NULL value in Employee column wherever we have APPROVED status in job status column and also, I don't want to count ASSIGNED values.

@UxerHub see updated original post

yes I saw it but as I said it does not work for me because we have a NULL value in Employee column wherever we have APPROVED status in job status column so it returns 0 AND I want to count every APPROVED status from a single job for an employee  it should be 4 for Jack as per your data

oh - so if the job id 1023 is assigned to jack and then it gets approved, it come back as 'null' in the approved row for 1023? And you're supposed to know that jack who was assigned job 1023 was the one who got the approved job because it shares the job id?

Perfect and also if Jack has multiple APPROVED job status then need to count that each approved status. So if Jack has 4 approved job status in the entire data then it should return 4.

Ok so I'm not sure there's actually a way to do it given the parameters you have given. I can get the overall amount of NULLs that show up for a given job code, but there's no way to track that a particular NULL can be traced back to a particular person. Iif you had 2 people assigned to job code 1001, and one person got it approved, you would need to have that persons name in the employee category, not NULL
